# Why can my object not access it's own private member variable? [C++]

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class called `class Car`, which has be instantiated as the object `Car car1`. One of the member variables of Car is `Car::width`, but when I try to execute the line

```
cout << car1.width << endl;
```

from `main()` I am told that this is not possible because `Car::width` is private. It was my understanding that private members could be accessed by the objects of the class to which they belong, but this situation has me completely stumped. What's the deal with private members being accesses by their own objects?

Comment: What function is that statement in?  That makes the difference to whether the access is "by the object".

Comment: Unless main() is the name of a function of 'Car' I don't understand why you think it's attempt at accessing the width variable qualifies in the statement, "...private members could be accessed by the object of the class to which they belong."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Private members are accessible by the *methods* of the same class to which they belong.

Comment: IMHO, *method* is too ambiguous a term in C++ to be used.  Normally, a 'method' is what an object does in response to a "message" sent to it.  In C you implement "methods" with functions that operate on a struct representing the object.  In C++ you can override operators such that the message "<<" could be implemented by a member function or a non-member function; thus either can be considered the "method" for that message.  Only member functions and friends have the access you're claiming methods have.  I'd say your answer is ambiguous and possibly in error.

Comment: "Method" is usual C++ jargon for "member functions". Even C++ faq uses this heavily, for example: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/classes-and-objects.html#faq-7.7

Answer (score 2):

`Car` can access `width`. But in your example it's **you** who's trying to access `width`. This is exactly the meaning of `private`.

Answer (score 2):

It can be accessed from within a member function, not outside like you have it here. The whole point of a private variable is to prevent exactly what you are trying to do, namely disallow users of the class to use the member variable.

Answer (score 2):

If the accessing function (`main` in this case) is not a member or `friend` of your class `Car`, then the compiler is correct in saying that `private` member `width` is off-limits in this context.

When you think about it, if anybody who could create a `Car` could access its `private` members, privacy would not mean very much.  You make the constructor `public` to allow creation of the object, but hide the created object's data members from such users to properly encapsulate them.  You limit the manipulation of the class's `private` internals to what's allowed by legal usage of the class's `public` or `protected` members.

Answer (score 0):

A method on class Car can access the `width` member, but your code (the one doing the `cout`) cannot.

Answer (score -1):

```
cout << car1.width
```

This isn't `car1` trying to get to `width` -- it's `cout` trying to get to `width`.  `cout` isn't a member of `car1` so since `width` is private, it fails.

Comment: Misleading.  `cout` has nothing to do with it.  Only the current function definition matters.  This same statement is legal if it appears in `Car::print()`.

Comment: @aschelper:  perhaps you missed the part about this code executing from `main()`?

Comment: no ifs about it, you're wrong.  Your answer claims that, "it's cout trying to get to width," and that is just plain incorrect.  Maybe that's not what you mean, but it's what you said.  aschepler is correct in correcting you.